# CSS Filter Blur: Prevent Undefined Image Edges on a Blurred Image during CSS Transition

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, css-filters

Preventing an image from having undefined blurry edges can be achieved by adding negative margin, but during a CSS transition this fails.  How can you keep the edges of an image defined during a CSS transition while adding or removing a filter blur class?

Tested in:

- Firefox 37: works great!
- Chrome 42: the border where the image and
  the parent element meet the image flashed/blurry/undefined
- IE9: no so much...

Check out my example: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/dclappert/full/eNpRXg/)

HTML:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="container">
  <img class="blur" src="http://budgetstockphoto.com/bamers/stock_photo_spectrum.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="col">
<h2 class="montserrat">Hover Over Image</h2>
<hr>
  <p class="hind">Preventing an image from having undefined blurry edges can be achieved by adding negative margin, but during a CSS transition this fails.  As you can see, on-hover, the edges of the image become undefined/blurred.  How can you keep the edges of an image defined during a CSS transition while applying or removing filter blur?<br><br>Hover over the image!</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
  margin:0;
  text-align:center;
  background:#F8F8F8;
  height:100%;
}

h2{
  margin:1em 0;
  padding:0;
  line-height:1;
  color:#111;
}
p{
  margin:1em 0;
  padding:0;
  line-height:1;
  text-align:justify;
  color:#999;
}

.montserrat{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.hind{
    font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
}
hr { 
  width:100%;
  display: block; 
  height: 1px;
  border: 0; 
  border-top: 1px solid #222;
  margin: 1em 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  line-height:0;
}

.col{
  max-width:400px;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  background:#333;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-right:20px;
}

.container{
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width:10%;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-top:10%;
  position:absolute;
  overflow:hidden !important;
  border-radius:50%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px); -moz-filter: blur(0px); -o-filter: blur(0px); -ms-filter: blur(0px); filter: blur(0px);/*prevents image from overflowing*/
}

.container img{
  position:absolute;
  min-width:calc(100% + 30px);
  height:calc(100% + 30px);
  left:-15px;
  right:-15px;
  top:-15px;
  bottom:-15px;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.blur{
        -webkit-filter: blur(5px); -moz-filter: blur(5px); -o-filter: blur(5px); -ms-filter: blur(5px); filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Just a smidge of jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('blur');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I guess you are testing in chrome, am I right? Because it works fine on firefox.

Comment: Correct, I am testing in Chrome.  I should have definitely included that tid-bit.  I will add that to the description.  It works great in Firefox, it look mediocre in IE9.  I'm not as concerned about IE9 as I am about Chrome though.  If you test in Chrome, you'll see how during the transition, the border where the parent element and the image meet flashed/becomes undefined.

Comment: could you take an screenshot? Because I find something weird in chrome but I wouldn't say that the border blurs, I'd say it samples the background and shows a darker border than then disappears. If that is so, it is probably due to the newty of the feature, maybe you shouldn't worry, they will fix it in the future. Btw, I checked it making the image greater fixes that but it doesn't. If this is very important to you maybe you could add a svg blur that is more standard? Just a suggestion

Comment: @Vandervals that is exactly what I am seeing as well.  By adding the translate3d property to accelarate processing and setting the backface-visibility to hidden it seems to fix the issue more or less.  What is weird is that the issue of undefined image borders is quite common in regards to using the the blur filter.  The standard way of fixing the issue was to hide the undefined edges by making the image bigger than the container it is in, which I have done.  It basically applying blur where it doesn't belong?

Answer (score 2):

On Chrome you can add

```
  backface-visibility: hidden;
```

On your image, it fixes a bit of blurring problems.

Comment: This definitely also helped a little bit.  I combined this and the translate3d hack.  It more or less solved the transition issue.  Just still dealing with the undefined edges.  As others have pointed out,  it may just be a weird Chrome issue.

Comment: Nice one! At last, no messing around with transform.

Answer (score 2):

Filters on images (and also some animations and transitions) has much better results when applied on content that is in HW-accelerated mode. Try forcing the browser use that mode, most simply by using some 3d transform:

```
.container img{
    transform: translateZ(0.1px)
}
```

See this: http://codepen.io/ondrakoupil/pen/GJpaJo
It is smooth now (Chrome 39 on OS X)

Comment: Note: I turned on Autoprefixer in that Pen, so you might need to add some vendor prefixes to make it work in all browsers.

Comment: This definitely helped in cleaning up the transition.  It looks much better.  The only issue I am still experiencing is the border blur.  But it's at the point where I don't think it necessarily detracts from the user experience.  I'm just confused as to why the border that meets up with image still has this blurred area and artifact.